# Improve code readability on webpack entry point

Tags: javascript, webpack, require

So basically i want to improve my code readability on webpack.

I try to split the entry point so it looks like this.

```
entry : {
    dashboard : ["./scripts/monuments.js", "./scripts/dashboard.js"]
}
```

And it will be resulting in dashboard-bundled.js

The question is, how i can get the variable from the monuments.js to use in dashboard.js? Do i need to export it? Or can you guys perhaps suggest a better way to split the entry point?

Answer (score 1):

> how i can get the variable from the monuments.js to use in dashboard.js? Do i need to export it?

Yes, you must export them in order to use them in different modules by using import statements.

> can you guys perhaps suggest a better way to split the entry point?

You want to bundle your third party code into one separate bundle as these don't change often, and your application code in a different module, that way you can take advantage of browser long term caching of the vendor code which you don't want the clients to download everytime they make a request because if something doesn't change, the browsers will just fetch from its cache (better for you and the users)

Comment: monuments.js is not third party code, its also my code, i just want to separate it for organizational purpose. So i dont think its the correct answer.

Comment: Seems like you don't quite understand the true purpose of webpack code splitting

Comment: Im not trying to split the output, im trying to split the entry point so it can become one bundled code.

Comment: No no, you don't know what code splitting is, read the definition here, https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/. `Im not trying to split the output, im trying to split the entry point  so it can become one bundled code.`,  it is called bundling, not splitting, *there is no such thing as splitting the entry point*, **you bundle the entries and split the bundled output**

Comment: look i might be wrong on the wording, but can you give the actual answer for the question since your answer right now is not related. If im asking about code splitting I'll write about the code splitting on the subject. **This situation show us that you are the one that misunderstand about the question because you are too focused on the buzzword rather than reading the question properly.**

Comment: I thought you meant code splitting. Geez your question suggests code splitting too. If you want others to understand you, communicate clearly. Correct termologies are important, my initial answer was based on my understanding of your wordings. can you guys perhaps suggest a better way to split the entry point? seems like you meant code splitting, pretty sure other webpack users will agree. As for how to **organize** your code for better readability, it varies, it is **not** one solution fit all, it depends on how you style and write your code (meaningful variable names, using indentations...)

Comment: Ok im sorry if its not clear, let me try to phrase it in more technical,

if there is variable a in monuments.js, how i can refer it in dashboard.js? provided with above entry point.

Comment: inside your monument.js, just do `export variableName;` outside of any code block (top level within that file)

Comment: Hi, never mention it but sorry and Thanks Dummy,